# Remove file from pushed commit

Tags: git

I wanted to remove a file added by mistake in a commit in Git.

I tried this code, but was surprised that it remove the file definitively. who can help me please?
I was following this link, **edureka.co/community/14763/git-remove-committed-file-after-push**
they said that it's possible.

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git reset HEAD path/to/unwanted_file
git commit -m 'remove unwanted file'
```

Please who can help me? All my tests have failed.

PS: Let's say that I don't want top remove the file from my tree git, I want just to put the file out of the commit.

Comment: "I tried this code, but was surprised that it remove the file definitively." What do you mean by "definitively"? And how exactly is that different from what you wanted to happen?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel i want to remove it from the commit but not from my project. let's suppose that i m working on my branch A My commit should have my files F1_A, F2_A. What happens actually: my commit contains F1_A, F2_A, F1_B(modified and added by mistake). Hope that i'm more clear now .

Comment: The commands you have listed do not remove the file from your file system (working directory), only the commit. It should still be there and it should still be possible to stage it using `git add`. If the file disappeared completely, you or a running program must have deleted it independently of `git`. If this is not what you meant, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

In your approach you undo your commit then trying to remove unwanted file and committing again, this means you didn't commit before but your message says that you have commited and now commiting second time. Instead you can give it a try:

```
git reset --soft HEAD # now commit has been uncommited and files is not staged
git checkout -- path/to/unwanted_file
git commit -m 'New commit message'
```

Also you can check out git [undoing things](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things) if you haven't.

Comment: i didn't got you. For me i did a commit, push on git, then i want to remove the file to recommit something without this file.

Comment: Apologies if it was unclear or did not work out for you. What I am try to say is that when you run `git reset --soft HEAD~1` you actually undo your commit. Then you remove your file(or you try to) and then commit your new changes without that file. So your commit message didn't seen correct. My solution is you can run `git reset --soft HEAD` `git checkout -- <path/unwanted_file/` and then commit again. `git checkout -- <file_name>` will undo all your changes on that file but if you want to delete from git repo and your file system you can go with  `git rm <unwanted_file>`